# Passing classes variables in vba

Tags: class, variables, excel, global-variables, vba

I know there is a way to pass class variables in vb.net as such:

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    ' Declare an instance of the class and assign a value to its field. 
    ***Dim c1 As Class1 = New Class1()***
    c1.Field = 5
    Console.WriteLine(c1.Field)
    ' Output: 5 

    ' ByVal does not prevent changing the value of a field or property.
    ChangeFieldValue(***c1***)
    Console.WriteLine(***c1.Field***)
    ' Output: 500 

    ' ByVal does prevent changing the value of c1 itself. 
    ChangeClassReference(c1)
    Console.WriteLine(c1.Field)
    ' Output: 500

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub 

Public Sub ChangeFieldValue(***ByVal cls As Class1***)
    cls.Field = 500
End Sub 

Public Sub ChangeClassReference(***ByVal cls As Class1***)
    cls = New Class1()
    cls.Field = 1000
End Sub 

Public Class Class1
    Public Field As Integer 
End Class
```

End Module

However when I try to emulate the same procedure in vba, it doesn't work.
is it possible to do in vba (for Excel)?

Comment: You should show your VBA code, otherwise it's difficult to say what the problem might be. "doesn't work" is also kind of vague - do you get any error?

Comment: You can write multiple classes in the same Screen in programmes like Java.. But here in VBA you have to add a class module for that `Class1` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim c1 As New Class1
    c1.Field = 5
    Debug.Print c1.Field

    changeFieldValue c1
    Debug.Print c1.Field

    changeClassReference c1
    Debug.Print c1.Field

End Sub

Public Sub changeClassReference(cls As Class1)

    Set cls = New Class1
    cls.Field = 1000

End Sub

Public Sub changeFieldValue(cls As Class1)

    cls.Field = 500

End Sub
```

You'll need to add a new class module with the following code:

```
Public Field As Long
```

Comment: note that the default parameter is `ByRef` - you need to add `ByVal` before each parameter that needs to be passed by value. e.g. `Public Sub changeFieldValue(ByVal cls As Class1)`